# after sign_up/sign_in, redirect by the kind of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have two kinds of users: Admin and Worker.

each user has role_ids: if user.role_ids = [1], the user is Admin. if user.role_ids = [2], the user is Worker.

After the sign_up/sign_in, I want to redirect him by his role_ids:

if his kind is Admin, redirect him to: `localhost:3000/tasksadmins`.

if his kind is Worker, redirect him to: `localhost:3000/workers`.

this is my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

resources :tasksadmins

resources :workers

root to: "workers#index"
```

I think I have to do something like:

```
if current_user.role_ids == [2]
   root to: "workers#index"
else
   root to: "tasksadmins#index"
end
```

but current_user is not defined in the routes.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override Devise's RegistrationsController and modify the method `after_sign_in_path_for` according to your needs:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
    return admins_path if resource_or_scope.admin?
    workers_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add a single root in routes.rb and in controller we have to mention where we go..!

In **routes.rb**:

```
root to: "taskadmins#index"
```

In taskadmins controller you can check with current_user

In **taskadmins Controller.rb**:

```
def index
   if current_user.role_ids == [2]
       redirect_to "/workers/index"
   else
       redirect_to "tasksadmins#index"
   end
end
```

Comment: thank you! it doesn't work but I have to say that it was a good idea!